# 500 error when adding to cart for some customers

Tags: magento2, http-error-500

Some of my customers have some strange behavior (Magento 2.2.7) : 
when they try to add a product to the cart, the spinner is loading forever.
I detect a 500 error in the console :

```
mydomain.com/customer/section/load/?sections=cart%2Cmessages&update_section_id=true&_=1547657718709
```

And I have this in the logs :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\\ConfigurableProduct\\Model\\Product\\Configuration\\Item\\ItemProductResolver::getChildProduct()
 must be an instance of Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product, null returned
 in
 /data/www/mystore/prod/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Configuration/Item/ItemProductResolver.php:83\nStack
 trace:\n#0
 /data/www/mystore/prod/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Configuration/Item/ItemProductResolver.php(51): Magento\\ConfigurableProduct\\Model\\Product\\Configuration\\Item\\ItemProductResolver-getChildProduct(Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Item))\n#1
 /data/www/mystore/prod/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Configuration/Item/ItemResolverComposite.php(44):
 Magento\\ConfigurableProduct\\Model\\Product\\Configuration\\Item\\ItemProductResolver-getFinalProduct(Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Item))\n#2
 /data/www/mystore/prod/vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php(129):
 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\P in
 /data/www/mystore/prod/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Configuration/Item/ItemProductResolver.php
 on line 83, referer: mydomain/catalogsearch/result/?q=+test
```

I did not found any info about this error anywhere, maybe you can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved (if I can say that) : it was Redis session cache that was the source.
I disabled this session cache and all is working now (but I lost the session cache)